# TCL calling a namespace variable from a proc outside the namespace

Tags: namespaces, tcl

I'm pretty much a newb, and I'm trying to set some variables in a namespace which use argv, and then to call them from a proc outside of the namespace, but I'm having trouble understanding how to do this. I'm trying to use some code like this (but clearly this is the wrong way to do it):

```
namespace eval Ns {
    variable spec [lindex $argv 1]
}

proc p {} {
    set spec "::Ns::spec"

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to use `variable`:

```
proc p {} {
    variable ::Ns::spec
    # ...
}
```

Also possible is `upvar`:

```
proc p {} {
    upvar #0 ::Ns::spec spec
    # ...
}
```

or (almost) like you did it:

```
proc p {} {
   set spec $::Ns::spec
   # ...
}
```

This last possibility will not change the variable if it is changed in the proc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I understand the mistake I made in the proc now... but can you explain a little bit about what `variable` actually does? I thought it was used to set the variable just in a namespace, but clearly I got it wrong...

Comment: It can do that, but it can also be used to import a variable into a proc. See the 3rd paragraph of the [manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/variable.htm)

Comment: @KaleidoEscape The `variable` command creates the variable (if necessary) in the named namespace — defaulting to the _current_ namespace if none other is specified — and sets the value of that variable if a second argument is given. Finally, if it is in a context that has local variables (e.g., a procedure) it makes the local variable with the same name as the _last part_ of the variable name be a linked alias to the named namespace variable. Much use of `variable` is actually of a degenerate case where parts are done using defaults.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Thanks to both of you for that clarification!

Answer (score 0):

...Or make a call to return the value:

```
proc Ns::getspec { } {
    variable spec

    return spec;
}
```