# TCL dictonary from another sourced file

Tags: dictionary, tcl, proc

I am trying to use the [dict] command within TCL. The following code works flawlessy if I use it within the same local file without the ixc namespace and with the procs within the same file.

However, if I try to use it within a sourced file -- It completely bails

**rawrIxc.tcl**

```
namespace eval ixc {
}

proc ixc::add2Dict {var1 var2 var3 var4} {
variable $var1
puts "ixc:: $var1 $var2 $var3 $var4" ;#Debug in console, shows passed params
dict set $var1 $var2 $var3 $var4
}

proc ixc::getFromDict {var1 var2 var3} {
variable $var1
puts "something: $var1 $var2 $var3"
dict get $var1 $var2 $var3
}
```

**rawrSiteButtons.tcl**

Adds data to the dictionary. I assume

```
ixc::add2Dict "button" "comic" "buttonText"  "&#x1F48E; Comic" ;#Button text "comic"
ixc::add2Dict "button" "comic" "buttonUrl" "/comic" ;#Button URL
ixc::add2Dict "button" "comic" "buttonSymbol" "%1" ;#Actual button ID -- used in mapping
ixc::add2Dict "button" "comic" "urlSymbol" "%_1"]" ;#Button replacement symbol -- used in mapping
```

However when I now try to recall the data from the dictionary with the following

```
set buttons(comicText) [ixc::getFromDict $button comic buttonText]
set buttons(comicUrl) [ixc::getFromDict $button comic buttonUrl]
set buttons(comicSymbol) [ixc::getFromDict $button comic buttonSymbol]
set buttons(comicUrlSymbol) [ixc::getFromDict $button comic urlSymbol]
```

I receive:

```
can't read "button": no such variable
    while executing
"ixc::getFromDict $button comic buttonText"
    (procedure "loadSiteButtons" line 41)
```

even if I use:

```
variable button
```

I've tried upvar, variable and namespace upvar [namespace current] and now no idea where to go. Any help would be lovely.
Thanks.

Comment: not enough to go on: at the point where you are `set buttons(...) ...`, what is the value of $button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
ixc::add2Dict "button" "comic" "buttonText"  "&#x1F48E; Comic"
```

the add2Dict proc sets a *namespace variable* named `button`.

So when you call `getFromDict`, you need to specify the variable's namespace:

```
set buttons(comicText) [ixc::getFromDict $ixc::button comic buttonText]
```

Or, run the whole command from within the namespace:

```
set buttons(comicText) [namespace eval ixc {getFromDict $button comic buttonText}]
```

---

Having a second look at this: your calls are a bit different:

- the `add2Dict` proc takes a variable *name* as the first param, but
- the `getFromDict` proc takes a dictionary *value* as the first param.

You could modify the getFromDict proc a bit to take "buttom" as the var name:

```
proc ixc::getFromDict {var1 var2 var3} {
    variable $var1
    puts "something: $var1 $var2 $var3"
    dict get [set $var1] $var2 $var3
    # .......^^^^^^^^^^^ -- one argument form of `set` to get the value.
}
```

then

```
set buttons(comicText) [ixc::getFromDict button comic buttonText]
# .......................................^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

Glenn already provided working solutions, but for the sake of completeness, one may also consider the following:

(1) From within a `proc`, you may use the [variable](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/variable.htm) command:

```
proc someProc {} {
  variable ::ixc::button
  ixc::add2Dict "button" "comic" "buttonText"  "&#x1F48E; Comic"
  ixc::getFromDict $button
}
```

(2) From the top-level and in your interactive Tcl shell session (but also from within a `proc`, as an alternative), use [`upvar`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm) to create a link to the namespace variable from your current scope.

```
upvar "#0" ::ixc::button button
ixc::add2Dict "button" "comic" "buttonText"  "&#x1F48E; Comic"
ixc::getFromDict $button
```

See also this answer: [TCL calling a namespace variable from a proc outside the namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712153/tcl-calling-a-namespace-variable-from-a-proc-outside-the-namespace)